# how to extract package-links from pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I have a slow internet connection,and need to extract packages from pacman so that I can remotely upload them and get them from my work. Do you know any way to do that?

Comment: There is a massive page in the Arch [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Offline_installation_of_packages) that addresses your question.

Answer (score 0):

i found it myself.

```
pacman -[desired-arguments]p
```

like:

```
pacman -Sup
```

p switch prints output of desired arguments without executing it.